# Can the __LINKEDIT segment of a Mach-O executable be moved

Tags: mach-o

In a Mach-O executable, I am trying to increase the size of the `__LLVM` segment that precedes the `__LINKEDIT` segment (with a home-grown tool).  I am considering two strategies: (a) move the `__LLVM` segment to after the `__LINKEDIT` segment, producing a file that is not what ld would create (now with a gap and section addresses out of order), and (b) move the `__LINKEDIT` segment to allow resizing of the `__LLVM` segment that precedes it.  I need the result to be accepted for downstream processing, e.g. generating an .ipa file or sending to the App Store.

This question is about my assumptions and the viability of these approaches.  Specifically, what are the potential pitfalls of each that might lead them to fail?

I implemented the first approach (a) is understood by segedit's -extract option, but its -replace option complains that the segments are out of order.  I append a new segment to the file and update the address and length values in the corresponding load command to refer to this new segment data (both in the file and the destination memory).  This might be fine, as long as the other downstream processing will accept the result (still to check; e.g. any local signature is likely invalidated).

The second approach (b) would seem cleaner, as long as there are no references *into* the `__LINKEDIT` segment, which I guess contains linking information (symbol tables etc., rather than code).  I have not tried this yet, though it seems to be a foregone conclusion that segedit will be happy with the result, which may suggest other processing might also be happier.  Are there likely to be any references that are invalidated due to simply moving this segment?  I am guessing that I will have to update further load commands (they seem to reference into the `__LINKEDIT` segment), which I have not examined, but this should be fairly straightforward.

EDIT: Replaced my confused use of "section" with "segment" (mentioned in answer).

ADDED: Context is where I have no control of generating the original executable.  I need to post-process it, essentially performing a 'segedit -replace' process, wherein the a section in the segment is to be replaced with a section that is larger than space previously allocated for the segment.

RUN-ON clarifying question: It seems from the answer that moving the `__LINKEDIT` segment will break it.  Can this be fixed by adjusting load commands only (e.g. LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY, LC_LOAD_DYLINKER, LC_LOAD_DYLIB), not data in any segments?  I am not yet familiar with these load commands, and would like to know whether to pursue this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically the segments and sections describe how the physical file maps onto virtual memory.
As I mentioned in my previous iteration of the answer there are limitations on the segments order:

1. `__TEXT` section must start at executable physical file offset 0
2. `__LINKEDIT` section must **not** start at physical file offset 0
3. `__LINKEDIT`'s File Offset + File Size should be equal to physical executable size (this implies `__LINKEDIT` being the last segment). Otherwise code signing won't work.

`__DYLD_INFO_ONLY` contains file offsets to `dyld` loading bind opcodes for:

- rebase
- bind at load
- weak bind
- lazy bind
- export

For each kind there is file offset and size entry in `__DYLD_INFO_ONLY` describing the data in file that matches `__LINKEDIT` (in a "regular" `ld` linked executable). `__DYLD_INFO_ONLY` does not use any segment & section information from `__LINKEDIT` directly, the file offsets and sizes are enough.

EDIT also as mentioned in @kirelagin answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39413065/5329717)
"Apparently, the new version of dyld from 10.12 Sierra performs a check that previous versions did not perform: it makes sure that the `LC_SYMTAB` symbols table is entirely within the `__LINKEDIT` segment."

I assume since you want to inflate the size of the preceding `__LLVM` segment you would also want some extra data in the file itself. Typically data described by `__LINKEDIT` (i.e. not the segment & sections themselves, but the actual data) won't use 100% of it's space so it could be modified to start "later" and occupy less space.

A tool called [jtool](http://www.newosxbook.com/tools/jtool.html) by Jonathan Levin could probably do it for you.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 'segment' (corrected).  My starting point is an executable that I am given.  It has segments __PAGEZERO, __TEXT, __DATA, __LLVM, __LINKEDIT.  The first three segments will remain untouched.  Your points 1 and 2 are satisfied.  There are further load commands, including LC_DYLD_INFO_ONLY.  Your answer indicates to me that this implies that simply moving the __LINKEDIT section will fail.  I can do something more sophisticated, which I'll post as a run-on question.

Comment: I was successful (a while ago now, just revisiting this) using my approach (b).  As your answer indicates, (a) does not work. I cannot remember the whole list of adjustments, but the trickiest was adjusting all the offsets *into* the `__LINKEDIT` segment scattered around the load commands.  I was unable to use jtool for the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I solved this problem while solving another [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61293156/8746647).

> 1. define the slide amount, this must be page-aligned, so I choose 0x4000.
>
>    2. add the slide amount to the relevant load commands, this includes but is not limited to:
>
>       - __LINKEDIT segment (duh)
>       - dyld_info_command
>       - symtab_command
>       - dysymtab_command
>       - linkedit_data_commands
>    3. physically move the __LINKEDIT in the file.