# Extend section in Mach-O file

Tags: shared-libraries, dyld, conceptual, mach-o

I am trying to extract libraries from the Dyld_shared_cache, and need to fix in external references.

For example, the pointers in the `__DATA.__objc_selrefs` section usually point to data outside the mach-o file, to fix that I would have to copy the corresponding c-string from the dyld and append it to the `__TEXT.__objc_methname` section.

Though from my understanding of the Mach-O file format, this extension of the `__TEXT.__objc_methname` would shift all the sections after it and would force me to fix all the offsets and pointers that reference them. Is there a way to add data to a section without breaking a lot of things?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Kamil.S for the idea about adding a new load command and section.

One way to achieve adding more data to a section is to create a duplicate segment and section and insert it before the __LINKEDIT segment.

- Slide the __LINKEDIT segment so we have space to add the new section.

  1. define the slide amount, this must be page-aligned, so I choose 0x4000.
  2. add the slide amount to the relevant load commands, this includes but is not limited to:

     - __LINKEDIT segment (duh)
     - dyld_info_command
     - symtab_command
     - dysymtab_command
     - linkedit_data_commands
  3. physically move the __LINKEDIT in the file.
- duplicate the section and change the following<sup>1</sup>

  - size, should be the length of your new data.
  - addr, should be in the free space.
  - offset, should be in the free space.
- duplicate the segment and change the following<sup>1</sup>

  - fileoff, should be the start of the free space.
  - vmaddr, should be the start of the free space.
  - filesize, anything as long as it is bigger than your data.
  - vmsize, must be identical to filesize.
  - nsects, change to reflect how many sections your adding.
  - cmdsize, change to reflect the size of the segment command and its section commands.
- insert the duplicated segment and sections before the __LINKEDIT segment
- update the mach_header

  - ncmds
  - sizeofcmds
- physically write the extra data in the file.

---

1. you can optionally change the segname and sectname fields, though it isn't necessary. thanks Kamil.S!

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**
After clarifing with OP that extension of `__TEXT.__objc_methname` would happen during Mach-O post processing of an existing executable I had a fresh look on the problem.

Another take would be to create a new load command `LC_SEGMENT_64` with a new `__TEXT_EXEC.__objc_methname` segment / section entry (normally `__TEXT_EXEC` is used for some kernel stuff but essentially it's the same thing as `__TEXT`). Here's a quick POC to ilustrate the concept:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        printf("%lx",[NSObject new]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compile like this:

```
gcc main.m -c -o main.o 
ld main.o -rename_section __TEXT __objc_methname __TEXT_EXEC __objc_methname -lobjc -lc
```

**Interestingly only `ld` up to High Sierra 10.14.6 generates `__TEXT.__objc_methname`, no trace of it on Catalina, it's done differently.**

**UPDATE2**.
Playing around with it, I noticed execution rights for `__TEXT` segment (and `__TEXT_EXEC` for that matter) are not required for `__objc_methname` to work.
Even better specific segment & section names are not required:
I could pull off:

```
__DATA.__objc_methname   
__DATA_CONST.__objc_methname 
__ARBITRARY.__arbitrary
```

or in my case last `__DATA` section
`__DATA.__objc_classrefs` where the original the data got concatenated by the selector name.
It's all fine as long as a proper null terminated C-string with the selector name is there. If I intentionally break the "new\0" in hex editor or MachOView I'll get

```
"+[NSObject ne]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ..."
```

upon launching my POC executable so the value is used for sure.

So to sum `__TEXT.__objc_methname` section itself is likely some debugger hint made by the linker. The app runtime seems to only need selector names as `char*` anywhere in memory.

Comment: My case is case 2, where I am reconstructing a Mach-O file after compile time. Case 2, alternative A probably won't work (unless I'm misunderstanding you) because for sections like the __TEXT.__objc_methname, it is sandwiched between sections, without any padding. Alternative b might work but would require some time test.

Comment: I would have to test this, but could this be generalized for other segments like __DATA and __DATA_CONST?

Comment: I tried to add a whole new load command, with the data at the end of the file, but when trying to load it on my phone, I get the following NSError, `/Library/Frameworks/TestMacho.framework/TestMacho: malformed mach-o image: __LINKEDIT must be last segment`.

Comment: You'd have to insert the `LC_SEGMENT_64` before `__LINKEDIT`.I was able to squash `__TEXT.__objc_methname` into `__DATA.__objc_classrefs` and it still worked. Why do you need a new section/segment/ load command in the 1st place?

Comment: Well originally I just wanted to add more data to sections.